# MindMap in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I need to put together a team to build a silverlight based application that will read an xml file and generate a Mind Map diagram based on that file.

I am new to silverlight and I need to find out what skills do I need and how difficult is it to do something like this.

I expect the typical Mind Map features available in a commercial Mind Map software,  like the ability to open and collapse nodes and to move the nodes around the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pretty well known Silverlight implementation here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SilverlightMindMap

Might get you on your way to assess what is required.